# Babel with es2015 presets breaks on IE9

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-9, babeljs

I am trying my project out on IE9, but I keeps having a Exception `SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier` on the following line:

`function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }`

I think it's because `default` is not wrapping in quotes.

Just don't know where is this coming from

I am using the following settings for Babel in webpack:

`babel: {
  presets: ['es2015'],
  plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'add-module-exports']
}`

And following package version:

`"babel-core": "6.18.2",
"babel-loader": "6.2.8",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
"babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants": "6.8.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.15.0",
"babel-polyfill": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
"babel-runtime": "6.18.0",`

Comment: Sounds like you’re in compatibility mode. Run your HTML through a validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this babel plugins:

- [transform-es3-property-literals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals)
- [transform-es3-member-expression-literals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals)